# How do i loop through two lists to see if the variables are the same?

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am trying to make a script to loop through two lists of computer names, if the names are alike it has to set a '1' in the row if they are not the same it has to set '0'. For some reason there are only '0's in the list and the script is insanely slow.

```
$adcompdata      = Invoke-MySqlQuery -query "SELECT ComputerName FROM ad"
$ampcompdata     = Invoke-MySqlQuery -query "SELECT HostName FROM amp"

foreach($adcompitem in $adcompdata){

        $adcompName = $adcompitem.ComputerName

        Invoke-MySqlQuery -Query "INSERT INTO inv(ComputerName) VALUES('$adcompName')"
        Write-Host $adcompName


        foreach($ampcompitem in $ampcompdata){

            $ampcompName = $ampcompitem.HostName
            Write-Host $ampcompName


            if($adcompName -like $ampcompName){

               Invoke-MySqlQuery -query "UPDATE inv SET amp = '1'"

            }
            Else{

                Invoke-MySqlQuery -query "UPDATE inv SET amp = '0'"

            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

When i debug this. The first two values are literally the same both are called "015598793153" and I'm still setting '0' in the DB

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your data source format and check that the SQL commands are working ok - if you replace your statements with dummy data it works ok

```
$adcompdata     = @("Machine1,"Machine2")
$ampcompdata    = @("Machine1","Machine2")

foreach($adcompitem in $adcompdata){

    $adcompName = $adcompitem


    Write-Host "Comparing $adcompName :`n"


    foreach($ampcompitem in $ampcompdata){

        $ampcompName = $ampcompitem
        Write-Host $ampcompName


        if($adcompName -like $ampcompName){

           Write-Host "Same`n"

        }
        Else{

           Write-Host "NOT SAME`n"

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line,

```
if($adcompName -like $ampcompName){
```

To:

```
   if($adcompName -eq $ampcompName){
```

Comment: Still getting 0

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see,

```
if ($ampcompdata -contains $adcompname){
    #set to 1
}else{
    #set to 0
}
```

should work.

You could also make use of `compare-object`.

Comment: Still getting 0